# Hibernate binding more parameters to a query than it should

Tags: hibernate, composite-key

I strongly believe this happens because of composite ids in the entities. First I will show my scenario. I have three entities. One uses the other two as ids. And both have composite ids.

Entity 1 (Composite id):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TEST_A")
public class A implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="column1")
    private int column1;

    @Id
    @Column(name="column2")
    private int column2;

    @Id
    @Column(name="column3")
    private int column3;

    @Id
    @Column(name="column4")
    private int column4;

    @Id
    @Column(name="column5")
    private int column5;
```

Entity 2 (Composite id):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TEST_M")
public class M implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="column1")
    private int column1;

    @Id
    @Column(name="column2")
    private int column2;

    @Id
    @Column(name="column3")
    private int column3;

    @Id
    @Column(name="column6")
    private int column6;
```

Entity 3 (uses the other two as ids)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TEST_F")
public class F implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="column1", referencedColumnName="column1"), // shared
        @JoinColumn(name="column2", referencedColumnName="column2"), // shared
        @JoinColumn(name="column3", referencedColumnName="column3"), // shared
        @JoinColumn(name="column4", referencedColumnName="column4"),
        @JoinColumn(name="column5", referencedColumnName="column5")})
    private A a;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="column1", referencedColumnName="column1"), // shared
        @JoinColumn(name="column2", referencedColumnName="column2"), // shared
        @JoinColumn(name="column3", referencedColumnName="column3"), // shared
        @JoinColumn(name="column6", referencedColumnName="column6")})
    private M m;
```

Notice that columns 1, 2 and 3 from table **TEST_F** are used as Foreign keys for both **TEST_A** and **TEST_M**.

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_A" 
("COLUMN1" NUMBER NOT NULL , 
"COLUMN2" NUMBER NOT NULL , 
"COLUMN3" NUMBER NOT NULL , 
"COLUMN4" NUMBER NOT NULL , 
"COLUMN5" NUMBER NOT NULL , 
 CONSTRAINT "TEST_A_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("COLUMN5", "COLUMN4", "COLUMN3", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN1"));

CREATE TABLE "TEST_M" 
("COLUMN1" NUMBER NOT NULL , 
"COLUMN2" NUMBER NOT NULL , 
"COLUMN3" NUMBER NOT NULL , 
"COLUMN6" NUMBER NOT NULL , 
 CONSTRAINT "TEST_M_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN6", "COLUMN3"));

CREATE TABLE "TEST_F" 
("COLUMN1" NUMBER NOT NULL , -- shared by both FKs
"COLUMN2" NUMBER NOT NULL , -- shared by both FKs
"COLUMN3" NUMBER NOT NULL , -- shared by both FKs
"COLUMN4" NUMBER NOT NULL , 
"COLUMN5" NUMBER NOT NULL , 
"COLUMN6" NUMBER NOT NULL , 
 CONSTRAINT "TEST_F_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("COLUMN6", "COLUMN5", "COLUMN4", "COLUMN3", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN1")

 CONSTRAINT "TEST_F_M" FOREIGN KEY ("COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN6", "COLUMN3")
  REFERENCES "TEST_M" ("COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN6", "COLUMN3") ENABLE, 

 CONSTRAINT "TEST_F_A" FOREIGN KEY ("COLUMN5", "COLUMN4", "COLUMN3", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN1")
  REFERENCES "TEST_A" ("COLUMN5", "COLUMN4", "COLUMN3", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN1") ENABLE);
```

Now, what I'm trying to do:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.setColumn1(1);
        a.setColumn2(2);
        a.setColumn3(3);
        a.setColumn4(4);
        a.setColumn5(5);

        M m = new M();
        m.setColumn1(1);
        m.setColumn2(2);
        m.setColumn3(3);
        m.setColumn6(6);

        F f = new F();
        f.setM(m);
        f.setA(a);

        Session s = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
        s.delete(f);
        tx.commit();
    }
```

Finally, what I get from all this:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not delete: [F#component[m,a]{a=A, m=M}]
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

The detailed log shows this. First it loads f:

```
2017-01-16 11:15:38 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    /* get current state F */ select
        f_.column6,
        f_.column3,
        f_.column2,
        f_.column1,
        f_.column5,
        f_.column4,
        f_.column3, // unnecessary 
        f_.column2, // unnecessary 
        f_.column1  // unnecessary 
    from
        TEST_F f_ 
    where
        f_.column6=? 
        and f_.column3=? 
        and f_.column2=? 
        and f_.column1=? 
        and f_.column5=? 
        and f_.column4=? 
        and f_.column3=? // unnecessary 
        and f_.column2=? // unnecessary 
        and f_.column1=? // unnecessary 
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [6]
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [3]
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [2]
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [4] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [5]
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [6] as [INTEGER] - [4]
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - [3] // unnecessary 
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [8] as [INTEGER] - [2] // unnecessary 
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [9] as [INTEGER] - [1] // unnecessary
```

The parameters binding is ok, although the SQL is a bit strange because it repeats equal columns in both select and where, and has to bind duplicated parameters.

Now it deletes f:

```
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Deleting entity: [F#component[m,a]{a=A, m=M}]
2017-01-16 11:15:38 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    /* delete F */ delete 
        from
            TEST_F 
        where
            column6=? 
            and column3=? 
            and column2=? 
            and column1=?   // this SQL is ok, no column repetition
            and column5=? 
            and column4=?
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [6]
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [3]
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [2]
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [4] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [5]
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [6] as [INTEGER] - [4]
2017-01-16 11:15:38 TRACE ... - binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - [3] // trying to bind nonexistent parameter 7
2017-01-16 11:15:38 INFO  ... - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

Differently from the SELECT query, the DELETE statement doesn't repeat columns. But the binding process tries to bind the same way as previously, causing the exception.

Does it look like a bug to you, guys?

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 problems in your mapping, the lack of the `@IdClass` annotation and the replication of columns names in the mapping

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="column1", referencedColumnName="column1"), 
    @JoinColumn(name="column2", referencedColumnName="column2"), 
    @JoinColumn(name="column3", referencedColumnName="column3"), 
    @JoinColumn(name="column4", referencedColumnName="column4"),
    @JoinColumn(name="column5", referencedColumnName="column5")})
private A a;

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="column1", referencedColumnName="column1"), 
    @JoinColumn(name="column2", referencedColumnName="column2"), 
    @JoinColumn(name="column3", referencedColumnName="column3"), 
    @JoinColumn(name="column6", referencedColumnName="column6")})
private M m;
```

so the correct mapping is

```
@Entity
@IdClass( value = EntityAId.class)
@Table(name = "TEST_A")
public class A implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column1")
    private int column1;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column2")
    private int column2;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column3")
    private int column3;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column4")
    private int column4;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column5")
    private int column5;

}

public class EntityAId implements Serializable{
    private int column1;
    private int column2;
    private int column3;
    private int column4;
    private int column5;
}

@Entity
@IdClass( value = EntityMId.class)
@Table(name = "TEST_M")
public static class M implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column1")
    private int column1;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column2")
    private int column2;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column3")
    private int column3;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column6")
    private int column6;
}

public class EntityMId implements Serializable {
    private int column1;
    private int column2;
    private int column3;
    private int column6;
}

public class EntityFId implements Serializable {
    private A a;
    private M m;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_F")
@IdClass( value = EntityFId.class)
public class F implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "column1", referencedColumnName = "column1"), // shared
            @JoinColumn(name = "column2", referencedColumnName = "column2"), // shared
            @JoinColumn(name = "column3", referencedColumnName = "column3"), // shared
            @JoinColumn(name = "column4", referencedColumnName = "column4"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "column5", referencedColumnName = "column5")
    })
    private A a;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "column6", referencedColumnName = "column1"), // shared
            @JoinColumn(name = "column7", referencedColumnName = "column2"), // shared
            @JoinColumn(name = "column8", referencedColumnName = "column3"), // shared
            @JoinColumn(name = "column9", referencedColumnName = "column6")
    })
    private M m;
}
```

Comment: How could this work?
`name = "column6"`
`name = "column7"`
`name = "column8"`
`name = "column9"`
Table TEST_F has no columns 6, 7, 8 and 9.

Comment: _I can see 2 problems in your mapping_ Hibernate doesn't complain in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Andrea's answer is good, but `@IdClass` is not the best way to map a composite Primary Key with Hibernate.

You should encapsulate the composite id in an `@Embeddable` and reference it using an [`@EmbeddedId`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

In your case, you'd have two `@Embeddable` types:

```
@Embeddable
public class AId implements Serializable {
 
    @Column(name="column1")
    private int column1;

    @Column(name="column2")
    private int column2;

    @Column(name="column3")
    private int column3;

    @Column(name="column4")
    private int column4;

    @Column(name="column5")
    private int column5;
 
    //getters and setters omitted
 
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof A)) return false;
        A that = (A) o;
        return Objects.equals(column1, that.column1) &&
                Objects.equals(column2, that.column2) &&
                Objects.equals(column3, that.column3) &&
                Objects.equals(column4, that.column4) &&
                Objects.equals(column5, that.column5);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5);
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class MId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="column1")
    private int column1;

    @Column(name="column2")
    private int column2;

    @Column(name="column3")
    private int column3;

    @Column(name="column6")
    private int column6;
    
    //getters and setters omitted
 
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof A)) return false;
        A that = (A) o;
        return Objects.equals(column1, that.column1) &&
                Objects.equals(column2, that.column2) &&
                Objects.equals(column3, that.column3) &&
                Objects.equals(column6, that.column6);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(column1, column2, column3, column6);
    }
}   

@Embeddable
public class FId implements Serializable {
 
    @Column(name="column1")
    private int column1;

    @Column(name="column2")
    private int column2;

    @Column(name="column3")
    private int column3;

    @Column(name="column4")
    private int column4;

    @Column(name="column5")
    private int column5;
    
    @Column(name="column6")
    private int column6;
 
    //getters and setters omitted
 
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof A)) return false;
        A that = (A) o;
        return Objects.equals(column1, that.column1) &&
                Objects.equals(column2, that.column2) &&
                Objects.equals(column3, that.column3) &&
                Objects.equals(column4, that.column4) &&
                Objects.equals(column5, that.column5) &&;
                Objects.equals(column6, that.column6);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6);
    }
}
```

And then, your entities look as simple as that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TEST_A")
public class A {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AId id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="TEST_M")
public class M {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MId id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="TEST_F")
public class F {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FId id;
}
```

The `@IdClass` requires you to repeat the `@Id` mappings while the `@EmbeddedId` encapsulates them much better.

Comment: Using this `@EmbeddedId` approach may I still have column1, 2, 3, 4... as normal `@column` in A and M and have attributes A and M in F as `@ManyToOne`?

Comment: What I'm asking is: since I moved all my attributes to `@Embeddable`, my POJO "lost" all it's "data". Can I still have the attributes in the POJO without the `@id` but with `@column` and have them at the same time inside the `@Embeddable`?

Comment: That would break the DRY principle. The "data" is not "lost", it's encapsulated. You can still access it like: `id.getColumn1()`

Comment: Ok. I'll try. Anyway, is it against any rule to use multiple `@id` in an entity? If the answer is no, do you think the bug exists? Is it worth to create a test case to post in Jira?

Comment: You can use multiple `@Id` in the same entity, but you try to reuse them from two different IdClass which is not correct.

Comment: Let's try again:
Do you think Hibernate has a bug when it generates an SQL with 6 parameters ans tries to bind 7 parameters? In other words, are you interested in fixing this, or will it be a waste of time to create a test case to put on Jira?